# Raising an adjacency matrix to a power: Why does it work?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

An adjacency matrix $M$ represents the number of ways to travel between pairs of points in a network in exactly one move. $M^k$ represents the number of ways to travel between pairs of points in a network in exactly $k$ moves.

What I'm wondering is this: why exactly does raising $M$ to the power of $k$ yield this result?

Comment: Hint: Try to understand why this makes sense for $k=2$ first.

Comment: Similar to:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231841/powers-of-adjacency-matrix-determination-of-connection-in-graph

Comment: Look at the book:Linear Algebra: A Modern Introduction - Page 243 - Section 3.7 on Google books:https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=V-UbCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&dq=adjacency+matrix+proof&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgKahUKEwiZvPOnzsjHAhWLa9sKHYKaDyY#v=onepage&q=adjacency%20matrix%20proof&f=false

Comment: Take a small adjacency matrix and by hand work out an algorithm to figure out which nodes are reachable from which other nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a consequence of the definition of matrix multiplication. The proof can be done by induction.

For the induction step, write $M^k$ as $M^{k-1} \cdot M$, and then look at the $(i,j)$th entry, which is
$$(M^{k-1}\cdot M)_{i,j} = \sum_{\ell=1}^n (M^{k-1})_{i,\ell} \cdot M_{\ell,j}.$$
For a given value of $\ell$, $(M^{k-1})_{i,\ell}$ is the number of ways to get from $i$ to $\ell$ in $k-1$ steps, and $M_{\ell,j}$ is the number of ways to get from $\ell$ to $j$ in one step. Thus, $(M^{k-1})_{i,\ell} \cdot M_{\ell,j}$ is the number of ways to get from $i$ to $j$ in $k$ steps, if the penultimate vertex is $\ell$.

Now, the penultimate vertex must be one of $1, 2, \ldots, n$. Adding up these products counts how many ways there are to get from $i$ to $j$, since a walk has exactly one penultimate vertex.